# How to make use of programming challenges to enhance your CV?

Tags: resume, job-search

Could you please tell me how one could make use of good ranks on programming challenges web site (coderbyte, hackerrank, CodeEval) to enhance one's resume/CV?  When does something like this matter?

Comment: A CV may be initially reviewed by a non-technical person (e.g. HR), so be prepared to explain the importance without getting into too much technical detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they matter, in two cases:

1. When your rank on such websites is high enough to prove dedication
   and skill.
2. When you've won or placed well in an important competition.

If you find yourself in any (or both) of the two situations above, then yes, you should add everything as relevant experience on your CV. It will surely help with looking good when applying to any job, especially those that require quick and efficient problem solving.

The reason I've mentioned those two cases is because admission to such websites is usually free. Just being a member of a website dedicated to algorithmic challenges doesn't mean you're actually doing anything there.

Comment: Fair enough. How would you put that in the CV? In the achievements? as a hobby? or in side-work and open projects?

Comment: I'd add any competitions as achievements. High ranks and on-website activity would go well as side projects.

Comment: Good answer. I recently calculated my percentile rank on ProjectEuler.net and found I was in the 90th percentile. I soon added a line to my resume (as an Applied Mathematics major with a minor in Computer Science). I feel very proud of my accomplishment and I would gladly show any employer my self-created code files that helped me solve PE problems. Unfortunately, certain people post their own solutions to PE problems that literally anyone can copy/paste/run/solve. Because of this, employers might have a trace of skepticism if I personally solved these problems, but I would be confident to

Comment: - explain my solutions line-by-line or go through a coding interview with that employer. That way, they would know that I'm not just placing percentiles on my resume falsely. I recommend placing your rank/percentile/achievement on a resume only if you can legitimately demonstrate it to any given employer. Once you display your rank on such websites *and* prove it, the employer realizes you are qualified and will hopefully be impressed!